HTML выпадающий список с фото
Фотки должны быть полностью растянуты на всю ширину экрана (если открывать на телефоне, то по бокам есть пробелы) и между ними не должно быть отступа. Помогите пожалуйста.
вот код:
    <!-- Элемент 1 -->
    <a href="#hidden1" onclick="view('hidden1'); return false">
      <center><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/C17VR4G4/1.jpg"></center></a>
    <div id="hidden1" style="display: none;">
      <center><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/vZfk1zM6/1.jpg"></center></div>
    
     <!-- Элемент 2 -->
    <a href="#hidden2" onclick="view('hidden2'); return false">
    <center><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/L50KT60Y/2.jpg"></center></a>
    <div id="hidden2" style="display: none;">
     <center><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/0jhXj6Bf/2.jpg"></center></div>
    
     <!-- Элемент 3 -->
    <a href="#hidden3" onclick="view('hidden3'); return false">
    <center><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/dtLK0rL8/Slice-20.jpg"></center></a>
    <div id="hidden3" style="display: none;">
     <center><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/N0bNTCnL/3.jpg"></center></div>
    
     <!-- Элемент 4 -->
    <a href="#hidden4" onclick="view('hidden4'); return false">
    <center><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/t46Q3bdJ/Slice-21.jpg"></center></a>
    <div id="hidden4" style="display: none;">
     <center><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/w3KFHC14/4.jpg"></center></div>
    
     <!-- Элемент 5 -->
    <a href="#hidden5" onclick="view('hidden5'); return false">
    <center><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/7LyvXRXV/Slice-22.jpg"></center></a>
    <div id="hidden5" style="display: none;">
     <center><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/6pKJfSMh/5.jpg"></center></div>
    
     <!-- Элемент 6 -->
    <a href="#hidden6" onclick="view('hidden6'); return false">
    <center><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/HL0qNthC/Slice-23.jpg"></center></a>
    <div id="hidden6" style="display: none;">
     <center><img src=""></center></div>
     <!-- Скрипт -->
     <script>
     function view(n) {
     style = document.getElementById(n).style;
     style.display = (style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block'; 
     }</script>



Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Stack Overflow на русском — это сайт вопросов и ответов для профессиональных разработчиков программного обеспечения, энтузиастов программирования и системных администраторов. Сайт создан и управляется сообществом. С вами вместе мы создаём свободную библиотеку подробных ответов на любой прикладной вопрос по программированию и системному администрированию. Приглашаем вас ознакомиться со справкой, как задать хороший вопрос =>https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Добавьте в вопрос ваши текущие стили. И если вы ваши "кнопки" сделали в виде картинок, то их без потери качества не растянуть

Если вы пишите html в пятой версии то тег center забудьте...
